# How to Make a Volley Request to a Firebase Database with Security Rules Set?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, android-volley

I have no problem using a volley request to my firebase database when I set the rules as:

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
 }
}
```

However the request is denied witha 401 or 400 error when I make a Volley request to a Firebase database that has its rules set as:

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
   ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"
 }
}
```

I have attempted to use authentication to my volley request but it still wouldn't work. This is how i make my request.

```
String url = DBLINK+"/users.json";
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String s) {
        if(s.equals("null")){
            //Toast.makeText(Login.this, ""+getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.user_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            RegisterUserMyStyle();
        }
        else{
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                if(!obj.has(savedUsername)){
                    //Toast.makeText(Login.this, ""+getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.user_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    RegisterUserMyStyle();
                }
                else if(obj.getJSONObject(savedUsername).getString("password").equals(pass)){
                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Succede", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        pd.dismiss();
    }
},new Response.ErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        System.out.println("" + volleyError);
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Authorization", "auth_token=\"" + authToken + "\"");
        params.put("auth != null && auth.uid != null && auth.token.email_verified == true", "");

        return params;
    }
};

RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
rQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: How is `authToken` initialized?

Comment: This is how i get the authToken @ 
Frank van Puffelen
`user.getIdToken(true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GetTokenResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(GetTokenResult result) {
    String idToken = result.getToken();
    //Do whatever
    authToken = idToken;
  }
});`